# Использование ссылок на Activity в статических переменных. Почему именно это плохо?

Tags: android, activity, static

Я новичок в Java и Android. Читал, пытался понять почему использование статических переменных для хранения ссылок на Activity плохо. Я понял, что если "терять" значение статической переменной, переписывая его другим, то Garbage Collector не сможет удалить Activity. Но если я всегда "освобождаю" ссылку (=null), то ничего плохого не происходит? Кто-нибудь может мне доступно объяснить или дать ссылку на объяснение волнующих меня вопросов.

1) В исходном коде реализуется механизм в котором статическая переменная из класса MainActivitySingleton используется для доступа к главной Activity (в ней интерфейс пользователя) из запущенного Service для передачи текстовых сообщений с помощью функции showMessage, принадлежащей главной Activity. При этом данная статическая переменная инициализируется в onCreate главной Activity ссылкой на эту Activity и эта же статическая переменная зануляется (= null) в onDestroy главной Activity. Чем плох такой код?

2) Везде пишут, что плохо хранить ссылку на Activity в статической переменной из-за утечек памяти. Но если в onDestroy для Activity занулять (= null) соответствующую статическую переменную, то чем это плохо? Вроде бы onDestroy вызывается всегда и мы тем самым отвязываем Activity от "статической" ссылки и тем самым развязываем руки Garbage Collector? Какие здесь подводные камни?

3) При использовании этого значения статической переменной в Service я могу получить ошибочное значение? Т.е., например, в другой Activity получу "правильное" значение, но пока соберусь его использовать, то оно уже превратится в null (race condition), даже если речь идёт о бесконечно малых временных отрезках? Или, например, там возможен data race и я вообще могу получить "мусор"? Как с этим бороться и нужно ли? Использовать synchronized? Или проверки if(ref =! null) достаточно?

4) Как вообще обычно решается вопрос с передачей тестовых сообщений из Service в главную Activity для отображения в интерфейсе пользователя? Я вижу только какой-то глобальный буфер (очередь сообщений) в который Service отправляет сообщения, а главная Activity их читает (когда запущена) и отображает у себя в интерфейсе. Но как тогда реализуется подобный глобальный буфер к которому имеют доступ и постоянно висящий в памяти Service и время от времени запущенная Activity? Может у кого-то есть ссылки на примеры с подобными решениями?

```
// класс для хранения статической ссылки на главную Activity
public class MainActivitySingleton {
    private static MainActivity gActivity; // "статическая" ссылка на главную Activity, которая доступна из любого места в приложении

    // вызывается в onCreate (activity = this) и onDestroy (activity = null) главной Activity
    public static void setActivity( MainActivity activity) {
        gActivity = activity;
    }

    // вызывается в любом месте приложения для доступа к главной Activity (возвращает null, если Activity уничтожена)
    public static MainActivity getActivity() {
        return gActivity;
    }
}

// главная Activity, которая содержит интерфейс пользователя
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    TextView log_msgs; // для отображения текстовых сообщений от Service
    private static final String MSG_KEY = "Msg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        MainActivitySingleton.setActivity( this );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        MainActivitySingleton.setActivity( null );
        ...
    }

    // обработчик текстовых сообщений, приходящих в главную Activity
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
            String string = bundle.getString(MSG_KEY);
            log_msgs.setText(string);
        }
    };

    // отправка текстового сообщения в главную Activity
    public void showMessage(String txt) {
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MSG_KEY, txt);
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    };
...
}

// Service который запущен и выполняется в фоне и хочет отправлять текстовые сообщения главной Activity когда она доступна
public class MyService extends Service {
    ...
    // просто какая-то функция, которая отправляет текстовое сообщения в главную Activity для отображения его в интерфейсе пользователя
    public void someFunc() {
    MainActivity mainActRef = MainActivitySingleton.getActivity();
        if(mainActRef != null)
          mainActRef.showMessage("Just Test");
    ...
}
```

P.S. Пока формулировал вопрос, сформулировал и резюме для себя. Как представитель С и С++ вижу тут проблемы только с синхронизацией между потоками при доступе к статической переменной. Но, наверно, эти проблемы как-то можно решить средствами Java? А если я уже получил ссылку из MainActivitySingleton.getActivity(), то значит и увеличил счётчик ссылок на главную Activity, а значит Garbage Collector не может удалить объект Activity из памяти, а значит я спокойно могу воспользоваться полученной ссылкой для вызова функции showMessage, пусть даже потом это сообщение уже не будет обработано в главной Activity, если вдруг эта Activity уже уничтожена (но пока не удалена из памяти).  Или я, по-прежнему, чего-то не понимаю).

Конечно "потерянное" сообщение - это не есть хорошо и поэтому всё равно хотелось бы узнать как обычно решается данная "проблема".

Comment: в первую очередь вам стоит забыть практику С/С++ когда вы программируете на Java, тем более в таком специфичном фреймворке, как андроид. У объектов жизненного цикла, как активити своя "жизнь" и удержание ссылки на прошлый экземпляр не равно получению доступа к текущему экземпляру того же "экрана". google придумал довльно "заморочную" систему и проникнуться в ее принципы работы иногда трудно , особенно имея практику других систем.

Comment: Просто пока примите за аксиому, что удержание ссылок на объекты Context (к которым относится и активити) - очень  плохая практика, крторая несет только проблемы и непонятные, без понимания принципа работы андроид-приложения, баги. Для полного понимания, что там  происходит, читайте литературу по разработке под андроид (книги, документацию) и следуйте best practics андроид-разработки, а не опытом программирования на С придумывая какие то собственные схемы, тут как бы разные галатики ... ps: ВJava объект уничтожен = удален из памяти

Comment: основной смысл устройства активити в том, что она существует, пока видна на экране, когда она "закрыта" другой активити, приложение свернуто или закрыто - такая активити условно не существует и считается потеряной. при возврате на такую активити  будет создана новая, а ссылка на старую будет на "мертвую" и обращение к ней ни к чему не приведет (описание очень условное). В андроид активити не просто класс (объект), а системный компонент, который система и создает, он глубоко завязан на эту систему и простые принципы с ней не работают.

Comment: ну и вот получится, что вы удерживаете ссылку на компонент, который больше не будет использоваться, хотя и жив, создавая утечку. вместо него же создан другой. все, что написано выше, имеет много нюансов и не всегда верно, но для начала это самое простое в происходящем. Как бы на все типовые задачи уже есть готовые паттерны и отработанные практики, основные из них отлично описаны в документации. стоит придерживаться их, а не изобретать собственный треугольный велосипед. все как бы уже придумали и отработали давно

Comment: Всё что вы сказали я понимаю и согласен. И про "порочную" практику C/C++ и про изобретение велосипеда. В том числе уже прочёл и понимаю принципы работы с Activity и про время их жизни и про ситуации в которых они невидимы на экране или частично перекрыты и когда они "уничтожаются" (то есть вызвана функция onDestroy) и про то, что они после этого ещё "живы" в памяти до сборщика мусора. В том числе я понимаю, что если на Activity осталась где-то ссылка, то сборщик мусора её не удалит из памяти и произойдёт "утечка памяти".

Comment: И я уже написал ниже, что мне посоветовали другие способы для передачи текстовых сообщений из Service  в Activity. Но, в принципе, как я видел есть люди которые используют статические ссылки на Activity (только рекомендуется лучше использовать WeakReference). Поэтому уже просто для более глубокого понимания хотелось бы выяснить будет ли работать мой код. ВРОДЕ БЫ он будет работать (пусть и как костыль или велосипед). Но если нет, то хотелось бы узнать почему.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, функция onDestroy вызывается всегда для "уничтожающейся" Activity (за исключением случаев, когда убивается весь процесс), а значит своим обнулением (= null) статической ссылки на эту Activity мы гарантируем, что "освободим" данную Activity для сборщика мусора. А ещё можно использовать в качестве статической ссылки WeakReference и тогда вообще не нужно будет занулять в onDestroy, а можно будет просто использовать isDestroyed в месте получения ссылки.

Comment: я не могу ответить что то определенное по вашему вопросу (потому и не стал писать ответ), так как такой вариант взаимодействия с активити не рассматривал в принципе. Однако можно уверенно сказать, что удержание ссылки на активити (в любом виде и удастся ли вам в дальнейшем освободить ее) не лучшее решение уже в плане того, что она может стать не валидной в непредсказуемое время при определенных обстоятельствах. существуют надежные инструменты фреймворка для взаимодействия между компонентами жизненного цикла, лучше использовать их во избежании непонятного поведения.

Answer (score 1):

Вызов `onDestroy` [не гарантирован](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy()). Передавать данные между компонентами (Activity <-> Service) можно с помощью [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager). В частности пункт 4 очень просто решается с помощью `BroadcastReceiver`-ов.

Comment: Как я понимаю вызов onDestroy не гарантирован только в случае уничтожения всего процесса приложения: "There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away." А в таком случае меня уже мало волнует, что там будет со статическими ссылками. Я прав?

Comment: И спасибо за LocalBroadcastManager. Мне уже в другом месте подсказали, что если Service запущен в том же процессе, что и Activity, то можно использовать либо Callback + Binder, либо ваш вариант с LocalBroadcastManager. А если Service с Activity в разных процессах, то через Broadcast.